# Apache Beam: Unable to serialize DoFnWithExecutionInformation because of PipelineOptions not serializable

Tags: java, serialization, google-cloud-dataflow, beam

Getting the following error when running my Beam pipeline:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize DoFnWithExecutionInformation{doFn=WriteWithAppendToGoFile$CreateTrailerDoFn@57b711b6, mainOutputTag=Tag, sideInputMapping={}, schemaInformation=DoFnSchemaInformation{elementConverters=[], fieldAccessDescriptor=*}}
>
> Cause: java.io.NotSerializableException: PipelineOptions objects are not serializable and should not be embedded into transforms (did you capture a PipelineOptions object in a field or in an anonymous class?). Instead, if you're using a DoFn, access PipelineOptions at runtime via ProcessContext/StartBundleContext/FinishBundleContext.getPipelineOptions(), or pre-extract necessary fields from PipelineOptions at pipeline construction time.

Code

```
private class CreateTrailerDoFn<T extends Extract> extends DoFn <T,String> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
        final int[] count = {0};
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new java.util.Date());
        T data = context.element();
        data.getContent().forEach(row -> {
            LOG.info(String.format("data : %s", row));
            count[0]++;
        });
        String trailerRow = String.format("%s,%s", count[0], timeStamp);
        LOG.info(trailerRow);
        context.output(trailerRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that an inner class? Can you make it static? There are a few scenarios in which the instance of the "parent" class is serialized with the underlying DoFn instance, and it seems that it contains PipelineOptions member -- which is not a Serializable class.

Comment: Yes converting the inner class to static has fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error you have pasted comes from some part of your code outside what you pasted. The error message does indicate what to do, and the answer by @bruno-volpato is most likely the issue.