# Getting unable to serialize DoFnWithExecutionInformation getting this error while building TableRow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am trying to Convert PCollection of Strings into Pcollection of BQ TableRow.
My Apache beam version is 2.41 and JAVA 11. I tried multiple ways but could not able to fix this error.
TableSchema is loaded from avro file and providing it to pcollection as ValueProvider.
Please help me to fix this.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
        options.setRunner(DirectRunner.class);
        options.setTempLocation("data/temp/");
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        BeamShemaUtil beamShemaUtil = new BeamShemaUtil("data/ship_data_schema.avsc");
        TableSchema tableSchema = beamShemaUtil.convertBQTableSchema();
        ValueProvider<TableSchema> ts= ValueProvider.StaticValueProvider.of(tableSchema);

        PCollection<String>   pc1 = p.apply(TextIO.read().from("data/ship_data.csv"));
        PCollection<TableRow> pc2 = pc1.apply(MapElements.via(new ConvertStringToTableRow(ts))) ;
        PipelineResult result = p.run();
        result.waitUntilFinish();
```

SimpleFunction Class

```
 public static  class ConvertStringToTableRow extends SimpleFunction<String, TableRow> {
        ValueProvider<TableSchema>  tableSchema;
        public  ConvertStringToTableRow(ValueProvider<TableSchema> tableSchema) {
            this.tableSchema = tableSchema;
        }
public TableRow buildTableRow(TableSchema sc,String[] arr) {
            List<TableFieldSchema> fieldSchemaList = sc.getFields();
            List<String> data = Arrays.stream(arr).collect(Collectors.toList());
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            TableCell record = new TableCell();
            List<TableCell> tc = new ArrayList<TableCell>();

            for ( int i = 0; i < fieldSchemaList.size(); i++  ){
                TableFieldSchema sc2 = fieldSchemaList.get(i);
                String fieldName = sc2.getName();
                String fieldType = sc2.getType();
                String fieldValue = data.get(i);

                if (fieldValue.isEmpty()) {
                    record.set(fieldName,null);
                    tc.add(record);
                }
                else {
                    switch (fieldType) {
                        case "STRING":
                           record.set(fieldName,fieldValue);
                           tc.add(record);
                        case "BYTES":
                            record.set(fieldName,fieldValue.getBytes());
                            tc.add(record);
                        case "INT64":
                            record.set(fieldName,Integer.valueOf(fieldValue));
                            tc.add(record);
                        case "INTEGER":
                            record.set(fieldName,Integer.valueOf(fieldValue));
                            tc.add(record);
                        case "FLOAT64":
                            record.set(fieldName,Float.valueOf(fieldValue));
                            tc.add(record);
                        case "FLOAT":
                            record.set(fieldName,Float.valueOf(fieldValue));
                            tc.add(record);
                        case "BOOL":
                        case "BOOLEAN":
                        case "NUMERIC":
                            record.set(fieldName,Integer.valueOf(fieldValue));
                            tc.add(record);
                        case "TIMESTAMP":
                        case "TIME":
                        case "DATE":
                        case "DATETIME":
                        case "STRUCT":
                        case "RECORD":
                        default:
                            //  row.set(fieldName,fieldValue);
                            //  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported BQ Data Type");
                    }
                }

            }
            return  row.setF(tc);

        }
@Override
        public TableRow apply(String element) {
            String[] arr = element.split(",");

           // BeamShemaUtil beamShemaUtil = new BeamShemaUtil("data/ship_data_schema.avsc");
           // TableSchema tableSchema = beamShemaUtil.convertBQTableSchema();
            TableRow row = buildTableRow(tableSchema.get(), arr);
            return row;
        }
```

Error Messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize DoFnWithExecutionInformation{doFn=org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1@270a620, mainOutputTag=Tag<output>, sideInputMapping={}, schemaInformation=DoFnSchemaInformation{elementConverters=[], fieldAccessDescriptor=*}}
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:59)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.translateDoFn(ParDoTranslation.java:737)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation$1.translateDoFn(ParDoTranslation.java:268)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.payloadForParDoLike(ParDoTranslation.java:877)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.translateParDo(ParDoTranslation.java:264)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.translateParDo(ParDoTranslation.java:225)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation$ParDoTranslator.translate(ParDoTranslation.java:191)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.PTransformTranslation.toProto(PTransformTranslation.java:248)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.getParDoPayload(ParDoTranslation.java:788)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.ParDoTranslation.isSplittable(ParDoTranslation.java:803)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.PTransformMatchers$6.matches(PTransformMatchers.java:274)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$2.visitPrimitiveTransform(Pipeline.java:290)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:593)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$500(TransformHierarchy.java:240)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:214)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:469)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replace(Pipeline.java:268)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.replaceAll(Pipeline.java:218)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.performRewrites(DirectRunner.java:254)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:175)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:323)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:309)
    at BuildWriteBQTableRowExample01.main(BuildWriteBQTableRowExample01.java:50)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableSchema
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1379)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1175)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:55)
    ... 26 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you a solution, it's not perfect but I hope it can help.

You can use your own structure for table schema, and convert `TableFieldSchema` to a custom created object that implements `Serializable`, example :

```java
public class MyTableSchemaFields implement Serializable {
     private String fieldName;
     private String fieldType;
     
     // Constructor
     .....

     // Getters and setters
     .......
}

public List<MyTableSchemaFields> toMyTableSchemaFields(final List<TableFieldSchema> schemaFields) {
    return schemaFields.stream()
                .map(this::toMyTableSchemaField)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}


public List<MyTableSchemaFields> toMyTableSchemaField(final TableFieldSchema schemaField) {
    MyTableSchemaFields field = new MyTableSchemaFields();
    field.setFieldName(schemaField.getName());
    field.setFieldType(schemaField.getType());

    return field;
}
```

Then in the rest of your program, use `MyTableSchemaFields` instead of `TableFieldSchema` :

```java
public static  class ConvertStringToTableRow extends SerializableFunction<String, TableRow> {
        List<MyTableSchemaFields>  schemaFields;
        public  ConvertStringToTableRow(List<MyTableSchemaFields> schemaFields) {
            this.schemaFields = schemaFields;
        }

public TableRow buildTableRow(List<MyTableSchemaFields> schemaFields,String[] arr) {
            ...........
```

For the class `ConvertStringToTableRow` I used a `SerializableFunction` in my example instead of `SimpleFunction`.

Comment: Thank You @Mazlum. That worked for me.  as @Bruno explained above 
Below native BQ Classes are not implemented with java.io.Serializable interface , So we can't use them in any Beam PTransformations. 

```com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableFieldSchema
com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableReference
com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow
com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableSchema```

Comment: If anyone trying to sync the data into BQ Tables from file sources or vice versa 
1. CSV files 
Convert PCollection<String> to PCollection<Row> (apache beam row) then you can convert to BQ Row easily BigQueryUtils.<Row>toTableRow()
2. AVRO & PARQUET 
Read file as  PCollection<GenericRecord>. BigQueryIO accepts GenericRecords and insert into BQ Tables

Comment: 3. JSON 
Read Json files as PCollection<String> then use org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowJsonCoder to Convert to PCollection<TableRow>.
com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow is not implemented with java.io.Serializable interface so you can't Build BQ TableRow directly. 
I hope, this info will be helpful to someone who is new to Dataflow/Beam.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[TableSchema](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/TableSchema.html) is not [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html), so the JVM/Runner can't copy your the instance wrapped in the StaticValueProvider. This is similar to the issue seen here: [Read specific record(s) from Dynamo using Apache Beam DynamoDBIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74279951/read-specific-records-from-dynamo-using-apache-beam-dynamodbio)

Please check https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#user-code-serializability for more information.

In your specific scenario, my recommendation would be creating the TableSchema within the ValueProvider itself instead of relying on serialization.
While I haven't tested with your code, I believe something similar is sufficient:

```java
PCollection<String>   pc1 = p.apply(TextIO.read().from("data/ship_data.csv"));
PCollection<TableRow> pc2 = pc1.apply(MapElements.via(
             new ConvertStringToTableRow(
                () -> new BeamShemaUtil("data/ship_data_schema.avsc").convertBQTableSchema()
             )));
PipelineResult result = p.run();
result.waitUntilFinish();
```